# Getting 'Invalid value for 'TargetFrameworkVersion'' VS2015/XamarinForms/iOS/Release

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ipa

We are getting error:

> Invalid value for 'TargetFrameworkVersion

when we are trying to publish iOS app. It is Xamarin Forms app. Both Mac and Windows have similar Xamarin version.

We have tried following things

1. Setting GenerateManifests and also removing the following block 
   < PropertyGroup >< GenerateManifests >true< / GenerateManifests >< / PropertyGroup > [reference](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/35641/#Comment_35641)
2. Turning off clickonce deployment [reference](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=16594#c0)
3. Removing TargetFrameworkVersion [refernece](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/35559/#Comment_35559)

We are able to deploy to simulators and devices. While create ipa for appstore, we are getting this issue.

Comment: I'm getting this issue but I can't build to any iOS devices or the iOS simulators. Works fine on Android. Followed your references above and I have none of those in my .csproj file. Running Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Comment: Went ahead with uninstalling VS, Xamarin, deleted folders and reinstalled. Its working fine now. No solution found for the above error though.

Comment: I fixed it by creating a new solution and copying over the files from the old project slowly.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by uncheck the checkbox under 
Properties -> Security -> Enable ClickOnce security settings